# Determine if an object has the same keys that are true

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I would like a function that takes in an array of actions, compare it against a list of users' actions, then return if the user can perform the action.

So basically, given:

```
const usersActions: { [key: string]: {[key: string]: boolean} } = {
      Bob: { eat: false, drink: false, sleep: true, walk: true },
      Alice: { eat: true, drink: true, sleep: true, walk: false }
};
```

The function would return if Bob or Alice can do a certain set of functions.

```
enum Actions{
    Eat= 'eat',
    Drink= 'drink',
    Sleep= 'sleep',
    Walk= 'walk'
}

const verifyActions = (name: string, actions: Array<Actions>) => {
    return actions.every((action) => {
        return usersActions[name][action];
    });
}

console.log(verifyActions('Bob', [Actions.Eat, Actions.Sleep])); // false
console.log(verifyActions('Bob', [Actions.Sleep, Actions.Walk])); // true
console.log(verifyActions('Alice', [Actions.Drink, Actions.Eat, Actions.Sleep])); // true
console.log(verifyActions('Alice', [Actions.Sleep, Actions.Walk])); // false
```

This works exactly how I described, but I can't help but think there's a better way of doing it such as comparing the array versus the object, maybe a one-liner with Lodash? This has been teasing my brain for a little bit and gives me a nagging feeling that there's a more elegant approach.

Thank you!

Comment: No, this is exactly the way to go and there hardly is a way to abbreviate it. You can write it as a one-liner by using a concise-body arrow function with no linebreaks.

Comment: I'd advise using `{ [key: string]: {[key in Actions]?: boolean} }` as a type. This way you're only allowing valid actions as optional keys, so you don't have to type all every time: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsRQN4Cgq6gUQEMEBeKAcmGPIBoc8ARAJyRAGszyATF92+3AGUANsGAAHTgGdRE-nigB1QsI4UA7irbksAXyxY4aKQihgpwJlPjJjALkxQA2m2ABPByd4BzALoOMF3coVlhEVBBfAH4HACMUFFFCEF0oVLJsBVwAIRRYgNwqBAcAMxULGigeVjZS8uBKmTFxBwQmMAaoTVVW9uA0yoB6QZVhKEJw4wE8GGEkOGACot6Oyur2Fc6miU3K3SHBtGE3KAADNo7T8cmQKWncAGFCJkSC7tqoMuEKz+PNgagwxKxxCUigIBQplGKHUwC4egA3FggA)

Comment: @Bergi, thank you, it's nice to confirm my own programming prowess :), the answer below also figured out the alternate solution that was bugging me.

Comment: @VLAZ, good note, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is simple and readable, just remove the curly brackets and the `return`:

```js
const usersActions = {
  Bob: { eat: false, drink: false, sleep: true, walk: true },
  Alice: { eat: true, drink: true, sleep: true, walk: false }
};

const Actions = {
  Eat: 'eat',
  Drink: 'drink',
  Sleep: 'sleep',
  Walk: 'walk'
}

const verifyActions = (name, actions) => actions.every((action) => usersActions[name][action]);

console.log(verifyActions('Bob', [Actions.Eat, Actions.Sleep])); // false
console.log(verifyActions('Bob', [Actions.Sleep, Actions.Walk])); // true
console.log(verifyActions('Alice', [Actions.Drink, Actions.Eat, Actions.Sleep])); // true
console.log(verifyActions('Alice', [Actions.Sleep, Actions.Walk])); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

With lodash you can pick all actions from the `userActions[name]` object, and then check if all are `true` using `_.every()`. However, this doesn't make it more readable or much shorter.

```js
const usersActions = {
  Bob: { eat: false, drink: false, sleep: true, walk: true },
  Alice: { eat: true, drink: true, sleep: true, walk: false }
};

const Actions = {
  Eat: 'eat',
  Drink: 'drink',
  Sleep: 'sleep',
  Walk: 'walk'
}

const verifyActions = (name, actions) => _.every(_.pick(usersActions[name], actions))

console.log(verifyActions('Bob', [Actions.Eat, Actions.Sleep])); // false
console.log(verifyActions('Bob', [Actions.Sleep, Actions.Walk])); // true
console.log(verifyActions('Alice', [Actions.Drink, Actions.Eat, Actions.Sleep])); // true
console.log(verifyActions('Alice', [Actions.Sleep, Actions.Walk])); // false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Yup, like I said, I knew my implementation was good; but the _.every and _.pick was the implementation that I was thinking of! On a completely unnecessary side note, which do you think will perform better? I would think my initial solution is O(n), would the lodash one be O(2n)?

Comment: @Nerdragen your solution would be much faster. Using `pick` and `every` is `O(2n)` yes, but that's still expressed as `O(n)` in the end. However, runtime is not going to be solely governed by the complexity. Lodash will, by necessity, have to do more work, even if it's constant. It's more expressive to allow for shorter syntax but at the same time, it must allow more kinds of input thus it has to spend time determining how to handle it. A direct native function call is going to be faster and pretty much the same length.

Comment: @VLAZ, nah, I know that, but I always try to find alternate solutions even if it's not the best one. I'll always implement the best solution, but part of the fun of programming is that there can be multiple solutions to the same problem, so I try to sometimes find those as well, mostly for fun, but also to test my knowledge.

I think Lodash tries to use as much native calls under the hood as possible anyways, but this was a fun way of getting to know `_.pick`

Comment: Though complexity would be the same O(n) for both, lodash does create an interim array that would be garbage collected, so I wouldn't use the lodash solution if you do this for a lot of objects. 

In addition to that, your solution is simple and readable, so no need for lodash expressiveness.